# jQuery Datepicker validate similar to onblur

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, onblur

I am using the jQuery UI Datepicker, and I want to check the date entered in the input field right after the mouse clicks out of that field. I would like to get instant feedback on whether or not the value is valid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought, but since it's the datepicker, i dont believe you can change the value entered by typing, so it should always be valid.

Comment: Exactly, how value will be invalid? Just make the field readonly to prevent typing. Datepicker itself will only allow valid dates of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".datepicker").blur(function(){
  var date = "4-5/2012 12:14:60 PM"; // replace this by $(this).val() to get your date from the input
  var validate = Date.parse(date);
  if (validate.isNaN()) {
    // do something if the date is not valid
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach a blur event on the datepicker input field and then check its value

```
$(".dtpicker").blur(function(){
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a validation plugin, try [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)